# Paginator Route don't work correctly on the frontpage

Tags: neoscms

The Route for a Paginator won't work on the frontpage (because of the / after {node}). Is there another way to achieve this?

````
  name: 'pagination page > 1'
  uriPattern: '{node}/page/{--itemPaginator.currentPage}'
  defaults:
    '@package': 'Neos.Neos'
    '@controller': 'Frontend\Node'
    '@format': 'html'
    '@action': 'show'
    '--itemPaginator':
      '@package': ''
      '@subpackage': ''
      '@controller': ''
      '@action': 'index'
      '@format': 'html'
  routeParts:
    node:
      handler: Neos\Neos\Routing\FrontendNodeRoutePartHandler```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uriPattern: '{node}?page-{--itemPaginator.currentPage}'` does work.

Not a real solution but could be a good workaround. If someone has a better solution then let me know.